# Post Links Using the Facebook Graph API blank

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

I'm testing [the example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi) for Post Links Using the Graph API on Facebook with PHP on a [Facebook canvas page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Aavee/354895081212182?id=354895081212182&sk=app_578708668876923). After I press login the page stays blank. When I test the same on [heroku](http://immense-hollows-2239.herokuapp.com/), it does work perfectly. So anyone who has an idea why nothing happens on the canvas page after login?